# How do I avoid gaps to a mirror modifier when I am scaling a model vertices?

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I was modelling the torso of a female body using the box model technique. Applied a mirror modifier and started to scale the mid section of it when a gap appeared. How do I fix or avoid this? Mirror Modifier Settings are as follows::
Axis: X - selected; Options: Merge, Clipping, Vertex G - all selected; Textures: nothing selected.

[image]

Comment: Check "Clipping" within the Mirror Modifier

Comment: they were not merged at the first place , to make sure they are merged select the middle verts and click S-X-0 ( resize to zero on X ), after they are merged they wont split again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all the vertices (Alt+RMB) that should be at the mid point, then press scale along the x axis(whichever is the horizontal one) and press zero (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>) this will align them all in a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid it by turning on *Clipping* in *Mirror Modifier*.

Comment: Add more details, screenshot perhaps.