# Mirrored object not perfect aligned after adding mirror modifier

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode, mirror

I'm trying to mirror my character but the alignment is not perfect. First of all I have configured the origin point doing the following steps :

1) in edit mode I have placed the cursor at the bottom of the character with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and then I did *Cursor to selected*

2) in to Object mode I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to 3D Cursor* to update or change the object origin to the location of the 3D cursor

But it didn't work, as you can see from the attached picture, the alignment is not good. Why?

[image: mirror modifier did not work]

Comment: possible duplicate: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44507/how-do-i-avoid-gaps-to-a-mirror-modifier-when-i-am-scaling-a-model-vertices

Comment: @cegaton : this is what happened : http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-04-10_00-49-36.png

Comment: @cegaton : I did what you said. the gap is reduced,but still there. check what happened : http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-04-10_10-30-23.png

Comment: I tried to make stay close the flaps pressing G + X but and then I have applied the mirror modifier,but they remain detached. check it : http://psychonews.it/dati/2016-04-10_10-46-56.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the vertices at the edge of your model are not aligned with mirror axis you'll have gaps.
To align the vetices do thei:

Deselect all the edges and select only the ones that form the edge of the model (Alt+RMB), and then scale those vertices to 0 (press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>).

[image]