# Origin to geometry, or center to center of mass don't align the mirrored character correctly

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode, mirror

I'm trying to mirror my character, but the aligment is not perfect. First of all, I've configured the origin point doing the following steps:

1) In to 'Object mode' I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to Geometry*.

[image]

2) In 'Object mode' I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> >  *Origin to center of mass*.

[image]

3) In 'Edit mode' I have placed the cursor at the bottom of the character with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and then I did 'Cursor to center'.

[image]

4) In to 'Object mode' I did <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > *Origin to 3D Cursor* to update or change the object origin to the location of the 3D cursor.

[image]

Also, according to this [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50432/mirrored-object-not-perfect-aligned-after-adding-mirror-modifier):

I have already selected only the edges that form the edge of the model (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right-click</kbd>), and successfully scaled those vertices to '0' (using <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd>) but none of these options did the task. As you can see from the attached pictures, the alignment isn't good. Why?

Comment: You are so close to success with your question above!    I suggest you change the title of you question to something similar to ......... How do I use the Mirror Modifier Correctly? .... You current title sounds like you are blaming blender and puts you in the wrong frame of mind.  Technically you have not clearly explained the flaw in your work in words or image.  Spell it out.  Do not make the reader guess ... even if they can guess.  If you have modeled the bird above the alignment can you take you 10 minutes or less and possible 1 minute.  You should view the problem as a simple one.

Comment: Is your problem .... 01 I see a sharp edge where I want a smooth one ... 02 Vertices are crossing the virtual horizontal X center of my model ... 03 ... both of these issues?  Neither? Something else?  State the flaws in your question.  You best work should be at the top where people see it first with the question.  I suggest one more image to show in close up the flaw in your work.  I have seen this question with the bird many days ago .. Did you delete a previous question?  Rhetorical question.  Please strike.

Comment: Some of this confusion seems to be from 2 questions.  Q01 is asking about the different ways of moving the origin.   Q02 is about having a model this is almost correct with the Mirror modifier. Cases 1 and 2 should be at the bottom of the question under a category ... Past Unsuccessful Origin techniques.  Cases 1 and 2 would be better as deleted or in a new question.  You have already a reasonable arguement that cases 1 and 2 wont serve your needs.

Comment: on point 1,2,3 and 4 I have explained what I did and under the explanation I have attached a picture to show what's happened after doing it. I have created another question trying to evaluate the situation from another point of view. If I haven't been able to understand what to do on the previous question,the solution was not there.

Comment: Many people less experienced than you have successfully used a Mirror Modifier.  Relax.  The official title of the writing and the question ... [Why?] are not well coordinated. You write  [the solution was not there].   I would say you have received numerous attempts at help from various people.  You are next to an oasis of potentially helpful 3D advice.  Make a new simple model and try the Mirror Modifier fresh.  You model looks more guideline conforming than before.  That is a +.  Fresh experiments may  bring fresh results.

Comment: I have fixed the problem by making the flaps very very close and then I have applied the mirror modifier and the gap is gone away. very thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

**Clipping**

Your model should have a series of vertices that will serve as the center of you model on the X axis.  Your choice of merge of the Mirror Modifier works best this way. You may have already done this.

[image]

Use the Clipping option in the mirror modifier to respect the X center of your model.  Use that in combination with SX0 (Scale Current Selection to zero X axis) which you discussed in your question. Be ready to turn the Clipping option on and off when necessary. SX0 can work with the Pivot Point to respect the Cursor position with the options in the 3D Window. If your cursor is snapped to the center line X coordinate, and the Pivot Point is Cursor then you may require less steps. Otherwise you may need to GX Grab X for the center line vertices.  Clipping option helps there, by allowing vertices to meet but not cross the X axis center line. Practice will improve the swiftness of this task.

[image]

A Simple Bird Model. Homage to ... Are you my Mother?

Mirror Modifier not active. Example Flaws on head and Beak.  Image below.

[image]

Mirror Modifier Active. Flaws. Note the Clipping option.  Image below.

[image]

Edit Mode with the 3 Flaw areas selected. Image below.

[image]

Edit Mode after 3 separate GX Grab X of the defect areas.  The Clipping option allowed me to quickly obtain the X location aligned with the X axis mirror. Image below.

[image]

Object Mode. Eye added which required to disable Clipping temporarily.  Clipping Back on. Image below.

[image]

Smooth Shading. Subdivision Surface Modifier. Image below.

[image: Smooth Shading. Subdivision Surface Modifier]

Another Flaw example.  A vertex off the X center line was moved to show an exaggerated vertex placement defect. Next a [Smooth Vertex] was performed a few times with this users default settings. The results were examined to achieve sufficient but not excessive smoothness. A round shape was desired not flat.  Lack of smoothness can be confused with center line correctness. Image below.

[image]