# Mesh keeps tearing appart

Tags: sculpting

I started creating a character model and I have been following this tutorial but I've watched it over like 3 times and I cant figure out what I'm doing wrong because as soon as I change from edit mode to object mode the body tears apart right down the middle and I cant seem to fix this? I'm still new at blender, can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the blend-file? And possibly also a link to the tutorial you are following?

Comment: As pointed out by @TobiasE, a .blend would be helpful in trying to determine what's causing your problems. You can upload it to [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), then edit your question and include the link given once the upload is complete.

Comment: [like this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/44507/935)?

Comment: Hi, Mar10us.W8, and welcome... @sambler might be on to it :) Please include, at least a screen grab to give us a look, or share a representative file, as suggested.